# TWTRComposer showing invisible Share and Cancel buttons

Tags: ios, mobile, twitter, twitterkit

I am using TWTRComposer to create a share dialogue within my iOS app. However, when the composer shows up, you don’t see the Cancel or Tweet buttons showing at all. After tapping around on the top left and right corners, I learned that the buttons are there but not clearly visible. Here is a screenshot pointing out what I am talking about:

[image]

Is anyone else experiencing this? and if so, do you guys know if a fix for this is in place or how to work around this? I cannot update my app in this state as it will provide a bad Twitter experience.

I also tried using TWTRComposerViewController but came to the same issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM, I found out that I was setting the UIBarButton tint color to white in some other place in my app for another class. So I had to set it back to Twitter color before showing twitter

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x3EA1EC)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Fabio Gomez's answer.

Solution for Swift 4.2 :

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black], for: .normal)
```